# VueJs: Two Independant & Seperate Routes/Views with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

**The Goal:** Have two separate, independently navigateable routes with vue-router.

**Details:**

How can I have two parts of a page that are independently routed with vue router? Say you have a page split into a `main view` and a `sidebar`. The `main view` is what you would normally expect from a view, you click on links and it changes the path and loads a new component. The `sidebar` is completely separate, no matter where you are in the `main view` the `sidebar` does not change, but the `sidebar` also has links that let you go to different components within itself.

With vue-router, I can have named views, but these seem to be tied to whatever the current path/route is, and cannot be controlled separately.

**Example Annotation:**

[image]

**Question**

Can vue-router have two separate, and independent routes/views that are not tied to each other? If so, is there documentation on this, are there router code examples?

**Note:** There is no code here, it doesn't seem necessary as this isn't a code issue, it's a `vue-router` use-case issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve separate independent routes if you use 2 `Vue apps` each with its own `router`.

A small demo in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m91e7s2v/).

I've used 2 routes, one with `history` mode and one `abstract`.

The biggest problem I see with this is that, at least out of the box, you cannot have a URL that points the user to the same view(s), as now you are managing 2 different routers.

The other is related to communication, you now have 2 different Vue app instances so you need to do something about communication between them. 
But this shouldn't be that hard

- if you are using `Vuex` you can set the same `store` object on both of them
- If you are just using a plain `data` object you can pass the same object to both instances and that will become reactive or
- you can always communicate over the same bus

Comment: I was considering this, but can the two vue apps share a vuex state?

Comment: They should, you are passing the store object to the vue app so they should be able to share. I say should because I never actually tested this. I did use the same data object on 2 different apps and everything worked ok.

Comment: @Radu Diță  , Good suggestion, now I can build my own modal for case 'search in main port -> edit in modal port' with 2nd vue app, but I get a question:  if my script try to maintain route state of 2 vue apps,  how to get references of these 2 vue apps (I need to get  'this.$root' for tracing something) ?